# Showing irreducible polynomial has a root $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{Q}$($\alpha$).

Tags: abstract-algebra, roots, irreducible-polynomials

I  am looking for a detailed step by step answer if possible as I have an exam tomorrow a past paper questions is given by:

Let a real number $\alpha$ be a root of the polynomial $g= X^{193}+49X^2+14X+14$. Where  $E=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

I have determined $\mathbb{Q}$($\alpha) =\bigl\{ \sum^4_0 a_i\alpha^i\mid i \in \mathbb{Q}\bigr\}$.  I.e., $a_0+a_1\alpha^1+\cdots+a_{192}\alpha^{192}$. I have also shown $g$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$, However I am unclear how to show how the only root of $g$ in $E$ is $\alpha$. My lecturer hinted at showing the polynomial only crosses the $x$ axis once may you expand?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why in the sum  is α at most 4?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a zero of $g$ and $g$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$, then $\{1,\alpha, \ldots, \alpha^{192}\}$ is a basis for $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ over $\Bbb{Q}$. Therefore, the sum must be up to $192$ and the scalars $a_i$ are in $\Bbb{Q}$ for $i \in \{0,1, \ldots, 192\}$.

Comment: Apologies I copied the question to a very similar one I posted as advised and just changed g, it should include all terms Upto 192.

Comment: In ${\Bbb Q}(\alpha)$, I'd divide the polynomial $g$ into $X-\alpha$.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: And please don't put dollar signs around each individual math symbols, but rather around complete math formulas (I corrected this for you, as well as replaced $4$ by $192$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we believe for a moment that $g$ has only one real root, then the fact that it has only one root in $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ is easy: $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ is a subfield of $\Bbb R$, so any root in $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ must be real, and therefore equal to$~\alpha$.

Now to show that indeed $g$ has only one real root, consider first the values on the interval $[-1,1]$, where $X^{193}$ evaluates with absolute value at most$~1$. Certainly $g(0)=14$ is positive, so if one can show that $49x^2+14x+13>0$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$, then $g$ will have no roots in that interval (either). But that is a quadratic with discriminant $14^2-4\times49\times13<0$, so indeed it fails to have any real roots at all. So we know all roots of $g$ must be outside $[-1,1]$. One clearly has $g(x)>0$ for all $x>1$, so we only need to consider roots $x<-1$. Now $g'(-1)=193-98+14>0$ and $g''(x)=193\times192x^{191}+49\times48<0$ for all $x\leq-1$, from which it follows that $g'(x)>0$ for all $x\leq-1$, so below $-1$, the function $x\to g(x)$ is strictly increasing and can have only one root (which of course it does have).

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, using Maple, the division of $g(x)$ into $x-a$ yields
$$g(x) = h(x)\cdot (x-a) + g(a),$$
where $h(x)$ is a polynomial of degree 192.

Comment: I don't know what the question is exactly, but I don't see either how this answers any question at all.